# cannot resolve symbol SetAllProperties in StructureMap.Net4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap, structuremap3

In my project i am using structureMap.Net4 (version 3.0.3) with StructureMap (3.0.3) . I configured the Ioc with following code  for setter injection

```
public static IContainer Initialize()
        {

            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                        {





                            x.For<ICacheManager>().Use<MemmoryCacheManager>();
                            x.SetAllProperties(y => y.OfType<ICacheManager>);
                            //x.ForConcreteType<AuthorizationManager>()
                            //    .Configure.Setter<ICacheManager>(y => y.CacheManager)
                            //    .IsTheDefault();
                        });
            return ObjectFactory.Container;
        }
```

But i am getting an error cannot resolve symbol SetAllProperties .  i already referenced this following namespace

```
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Graph;
```

Why i am getting this error ? how i can solve this ? or should i reference any other namespace

Answer (score 11, accepted):

StructureMap 3 has changed where Setter Injection is configured. It is now configured using a `PolicyExpression`, it can be accessed at `ConfigurationExpression.Policies`. I've attached a sample below.

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
    x.Policies.SetAllProperties(y => y.OfType<ICacheManager>());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting braces

```
x.SetAllProperties(y => y.OfType<ICacheManager>());
```